# Why does Qlik API returns Error 400 in postman?

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to use postman to use Qlik Rest API but it always returns this error. I also added the certificates for POSTMAN but it's still not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Authentication with certificates only makes sense if the connection is made through the "administration" ports. For the Repository service (`/qrs/`) that's `4242`.

If connecting through the normal route then you'll have to follow the virtual proxy authentication mechanism (AD, Form, JWT, SAML etc).

If `4242` is not exposed (and ideally it shouldnt be because thats an internal communication port) but still need to communicate with the Repository API im usually creating an extra virtual proxy with JWT authentication. Then im generating JWT for my user and use the token in Postman to connect directly.

And as Mansoor mentioned make sure that the whitelisting is ok.